# Another way to install Multiplayer HLAPI in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there any other way to download Multiplayer HLAPI in Unity other than installing it in pakagemanager?

This is absolutely important for my project and I couldn't find a way no matter what I searched

Comment: What's wrong with using Package Manager?

Comment: Probably due to internet problems, I encountered a problem with Unity and wanted to look for another way to install Multiplayer HLAPI.
There is nothing to show me in PakageManager.

Comment: _"Probably due to internet problems"_ - in this day and age of digital software distribution, there's generally no getting around that.  Unless say the package is available on GitHub in which case you could download a release manually via a download manager that supports **retry**.  e.g. _[Internet Download Manager](https://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/)_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from using github, the only way I found to download HLAPI was to get the HLAPI from a person who has already downloaded it, either through messengers or through USB.